# rails extracting code from view to helper (content_tag misunderstanding?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-tag

I got the following code in my view:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <% Photo.find_all_by_id(my_params, limit: 10).each do |p| %>
    <li class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag(p.url(:fb)) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It renders an unordered list with thumbnails. And it works okay - I see the list with images:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="thumbnail">
    <img alt="bmw" src="/assets/.../bmw.jpg?1364218949">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to put it into helper, like this:

```
module PhotosHelper
  def photos_thumbs_by_ids(photos_ids)
    content_tag :ul, :class => "thumbnails" do
      Photo.find_all_by_id(photos_ids, limit: 10).each do |p|
        content_tag :li, :class => "thumbnail" do
          image_tag(p.url(:fb))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I use `<%= photos_thumbs_by_ids my_params %>` in my view, it renders only:

```
<ul class="thumbnails"></ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: update: sorry, just not added params in the example by mistake - I do send it to the helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the each :

```
Photo.find_all_by_id(photos_ids, limit: 10).each do |p|
...
end
```

It return an array, not the string. Try  to collect it with 'map' and do a join

```
module PhotosHelper
  def photos_thumbs_by_ids(photos_ids)
    content_tag :ul, :class => "thumbnails" do
      Photo.find_all_by_id(photos_ids, limit: 10).map { |p|
        content_tag :li, :class => "thumbnail" do
           image_tag(p.url(:fb))
        end
      }.join.html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

It's beacuse at least the rendering is done by the useful method [capture](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/capture). This method put in output buffer only if the result is a string, and don't try a to_s.

Comment: OMG ! yes sorry, I forgot html_safe.

Answer (score 1):

What i found after seeing your code is, you are not passing the `photo_ids` parameter while calling the helper method.

```
<%= photos_thumbs_by_ids(photo_ids) %>
```

As there is no ids to find photos, so it is returning zero items, so no `<li>` items will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Try as follow;

```
<%= photos_thumbs_by_ids(photo_ids) %>

def photos_thumbs_by_ids(photos_ids)
    content_tag :ul, :class => "thumbnails" do
      Photo.find_all_by_id(photos_ids, limit: 10).each do |p|
        content_tag :li, :class => "thumbnail" do
          concat(image_tag(p.url(:fb)))
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: sorry, just not added params in the example by mistake - I do send it to the helper